# How can I request fonts for a web application not served by webpack-dev-server

Tags: css, flask, fonts, webpack-dev-server

Here's the situation

- Python Flask is serving HTML at `localhost:5000`
- Webpack Assets being served at `localhost:8080/dist`

My HTML pulls `css` and `js` from `localhost:8080/dist` with no problem. Fonts that I'm importing into my css on the other hand are being very difficult. Here's a screenshot of what the network tab shows within the chrome dev tools.

[image: Chrome Network Inspector]

It shows that all requests for `dist/SourceSansPro*` become canceled. Not even a `404` is being thrown. Despite `webpack-dev-server` logging information saying that everything is being appropriately served.

```
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /dist/
Hash: 1b12befb328bf596da35
Version: webpack 3.7.1
Time: 3629ms
                              Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf.woff   135 kB          [emitted]
       SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.eot   292 kB          [emitted]  [big]
       SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.otf   227 kB          [emitted]
       SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf   292 kB          [emitted]  [big]
       # ... all other assets.
```

If I serve the HTML from `webpack-dev-server`, and host it alongside the assets, then I do not have this issue. In fact everything works great, but the moment I host my HTML from flask, then I get this issue.

This sounds somewhat like a cross origin resource problem, but I have no idea how to go about googling this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [Dev Server Headers](https://webpack.bootcss.com/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-).

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    devServer: {
        headers:{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    },
};
```